# Export DataSet to Excel ASP.Net

Tags: excel, dataset

I need to Export DataSet to Excel, Exporting it is not the main issue, When I am using the Same Exported Excel File using 
following Connection String
  CS = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
                  "data source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

It gives me an error message saying External Table is not in correct format

Help Needed

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a better way by changing the Response.ContentType  "application/vnd.ms-excel", especially since you are using ASP.NET and not winforms.

check this article with full details on [converting dataset to excel](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/PrintFriend.aspx?articleid=36)

Comment: Manipulating Response Content types in ASP.Net is awesome!!! Here is a list of the mime type you can use... http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Answer (score 0):

When you do Response.ContentType "application/vnd.ms-excel".
You can just generate an html table. 
Excel will pick it op an open it and automatically convert the HTML to excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post I wrote that illustrates some of the various options for getting data from SQL into Excel:
http://www.officewriter.com/blog/2011/09/23/exporting-sql-server-database-data-excel

If you're using ASP.NET your choices are somewhat more limited because you need something that is both programmatic as well as scalable/suitable for server use, like OfficeWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found a perfect solution [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/23/writing-data-from-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx)

Just replace 'missing.value' with System.Type.Missing in the code.
Also remove

```
oWB.Close(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
```

and

```
oXL.Quit();
```

from the code. Otherwise your excel will get closed automatically as soon as it open.